# Standard deviation, standard error and confidence interval difference explanation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, confidence-interval, standard-error

I write some code to generate random weights (I define low as 50Kg and high as 100Kg) of males, then generate 100 samples containing 100 measurements (weights per sample) i.e. 100 samples and each sample contains 100 weights

The mean of weights for each one of the 100 samples are:

```
Output:
[73.43, 73.96, 74.3, 76.68, 77.3, 75.43, 75.72, 73.27, 76.36, 73.72, 74.63, 74.2, 76.43, 71.48, 76.47, 75.74, 75.71, 74.14, 72.48, 74.53, 73.17, 74.75, 73.79, 75.03, 74.54, 74.65, 73.16, 74.84, 75.86, 73.69, 74.76, 74.83, 73.53, 73.95, 73.14, 76.37, 75.36, 74.62, 73.38, 76.84, 74.88, 73.58, 71.71, 75.24, 77.96, 75.38, 77.56, 73.85, 73.25, 75.09, 74.24, 75.12, 72.09, 74.63, 75.35, 72.76, 73.44, 74.82, 74.08, 72.91, 74.99, 75.56, 75.37, 75.27, 72.16, 74.5, 73.65, 73.1, 70.72, 74.92, 72.61, 72.7, 75.01, 72.75, 77.05, 73.29, 73.02, 74.9, 75.8, 75.88, 74.42, 76.83, 73.85, 72.9, 74.45, 73.86, 70.95, 75.05, 74.04, 73.84, 75.52, 73.52, 73.01, 75.01, 73.49, 73.74, 77.05, 74.87, 74.99, 74.17]
```

I then calculate for that dataset:

- **Mean:** 74.4299
- **Standard deviation:** 1.4121603981134718
- **Standard error:** 0.14121603981134717
- **Confidence_Interval_0.95:** (74.1482851277224, 74.7115148722776)

I try to understand what those numbers represent (**Standard deviation**, **Standard error** and  **Confidence_Interval_0.95**) in a practical way.

The **Standard error** is the **Standard deviation**/10 (the sqrt of sample size). But what exactly represents? The **Standard deviation** shows how the **Means** are spread out, what about the **Standard error**? What is the difference?

The 95% rule of a normal distribution shows that 95% of the values lie in 2 **Standard deviation**s from the **Mean** but:

**Mean** + 2*(**Standard deviation**) NOT EQUAL **Confidence_Interval_0.95**: 74.7115148722776.

So what is exactly the relationship between those statistics?

Thanks

Comment: What's the distribution of the random variable? Is it normal distribution? Anyway, it's useful to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

Comment: Standard error is a measure of error due to sampling. Don't know if this would help, but here are some popular threads on the stats site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6652/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/158570/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26450/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32318/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33547/119261

Comment: @MattiP. yes it is normal distribution. I spend time reading and seeing video but it seems a simple thing is very complicated.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I see that there exists a statistics site in stackexchange. I searched for stats in all sites and did not found it... why the heck they call it crossvalidated? I will look the links you posted. Probably my question fits better in stats.stackexchange.com. I do not know how I can move it there

Comment: Your question is on topic on both sites. If you post this on the stats site, it is likely that you will be asked to go through the same posts I linked above.

Comment: I don't think it's that complicated. The calculation steps are laid out in "Basic steps" on the Wikipedia site. The hardest part is using the Z-table / T-table (depending on the case)